# Error adhoc couchdb java

Tags: java, couchdb

I am using Couchdb in order to store information from twitterdata. The database name is **twitterdata** and a document have the following structure:

```
{
       _id:2fb87b3376c2e5bf02086e66dd0009ee,
       _rev:de95a098b5bf9d327fd7af4ea8ea1ae0,
       lemmatizeText:how be you btw thanks for the rt gon na in dc anytime soon Love to see way too long
}
```

I want to select all documents from database twitterdata with all fields available. I am using **[couchdb4](https://github.com/mbreese/couchdb4j/)** library. When i try to run the code below the following error occurs: *Aug 22, 2016 9:25:10 PM com.fourspaces.couchdb.Database adhoc
WARNING: Error executing view - null null*

```
    String dbname = "twitterdata";
    Database db = this.s.getDatabase(dbname);

    System.out.println(db.getName());

//  ViewResults results = db.getAllDocuments();

/*  ViewResults resultAdHoc = db.adhoc("function(doc) { log(doc); "
            + "if (doc.lemmatizeText) {" 
            + " alert('da');    for(var lemText in doc.lemmatizeText) {"
            + "         emit(doc.lemmatizeText[lemText], 1);"
            + "     }"
            + " }"
            + "}");

    System.out.println(resultAdHoc); */

    // emit(null, doc);

    ViewResults resultAdHoc = db.adhoc("function(doc) { emit(doc._id, doc);} ");

    System.out.println(resultAdHoc);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Does the error occurs for view only or for every request?

Comment: The error occurs only for view.